# Can not import modules into android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, zoom-sdk

I am importing zoom sdk modules into my existing android studio project. But i can not finish the process as the finish button is disabled in AS. Please see the screen shot. Could you please help to fix this. or kindly suggest a workaround. i totally wasted full three days doing in several ways.

[image]

Comment: When you use the Import option is only for Gradle or Eclipse projects. You must have an aar file or jar file

Comment: @GorkyMuñoz there is aar file in that folder

Comment: I have same problem . I use 'Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 14' .maybe its a bug of Android Studio !

Answer (score 4):

1. Copy library folder to your application `root` directory
2. Go to you application `setting.gradle`
3. Add include statement into it e.g `include ':app', ':picker'`
4. click sync gradle

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Paste the folders in `root` directory and in `settings.gradle-add include` `:mobilertc` and include `:commonlib`